# sails.models.['CollectionName'] is not working in latest Sails Version

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I am trying to access Model component via **sails.models.['CollectionName']** as these CollectionName will be dynamically sent into this piece of functionality. But it is throwing undefined error.

```
 /sails12.rc3/myapps/api/services/UserService.js:86
    var findQuery = sails.models['User'].find({id: inputID
                                               ^
 /sails12.rc3/myapps/api/services/UserService.js:86
    var findQuery = sails.config.models['User'].find({id: inputID
                                               ^
 /sails12.rc3/myapps/api/services/UserService.js:86
    var findQuery = sails.config.models['user'].find({id: inputID
                                               ^
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Object.UserService.formNewData   
       (/sails12.rc3/myapps/api/services/UserService.js:86:52)
at Object.bound [as formNewData] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
at /sails12.rc3/myapps/api/services/UserInfoService.js:330:37
at fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:638:34)
at Immediate._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:554:34)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

Please note that **sails.config** is working perfectly fine..

I am using SailsJS 12 rc 3. ( I mean the latest Version at this time ).

Can you please suggest me about the troubleshooting in this regard.

**Update 1:** 
**Hi Jason,** 
In all 3 cases, the same errror.
I could technically confirm that you are right on 
  http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-models

Still, I am not sure, if there are any update requires in

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/models-js

currently in config/models.js,

```
module.exports.models = {
 connection: 'mongoDB',
 migrate: 'alter'
}
```

Please suggest if I need to update any config values in this models.js file?

**Update 2**

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/orm/build-orm.js
 I could see the following values for these global values

```
sails.config.models  { connection: 'mongoDB', migrate: 'alter' }
sails.config.globals  { adapters: true, models: true, services: true }
sails.config.globals.models  true
```

And hence mine is not working..Please suggest some options.

**Update 3**

Thanks Travis. sails.models['user'].find is working fine without no change in the SailsJS version. So, let me test some more time.

Ps: Not sure, why i am unable to add a comment directly below ( MAC / chrome browser) . So, for now, editing this question itself.

Comment: I hope the answer below helps. If you would like an additional resource, here is a chat room for sails.js, node.js, and waterline questions. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 1):

I think you're accessing it incorrectly.

Try: `sails.config.models['User']`

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the model name to lowercase.

`sails.models['CollectionName']` will not work, because within the models object, the collection names are all lowercase.

`sails.model['collectionname']` should work.

I'm not sure why this is, but I think it will be something in the building of the ORM in waterline.

edit : I think this happens [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/collection/loader.js#L56)